# Google Map pointers on click open jQuery Mobile panel weidget

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, mobile, panel

I hope someone is able to help with this.

Essentially what i'm after is if a user clicks a map pointer (using Google Maps) then it opens up a panel widget in association with jQuery Mobile.

This is a snippet of the code for default linking. But this doesn't work.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     window.location.href = '#test';
});
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `window.location.href = '#test';` use `.panel()` method to open panel.

Open panel by its' ID, either an *internal* or *external* panel.

```
$("#panel-ID").panel("open");
```

Or, open panel within *active page* without ID.

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage").find("[data-role=panel]").panel("open");
```